# No warnings in trivial uninitialized variable array access

Tags: c++, g++, clang++

Why g++ and clang++ are not warning about uninitialized variable access in such example?

```cpp
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    int main() {
       int tab[5];
       for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
           int a, b;
           cin >> a >> b;
           tab[a] += b;
       }
       int a;
       cin >> a;
       cout << tab[a] << endl;
    }
```

I'm compiling on WSL (Ubuntu on Windows):

```
g++ -Wextra -O0 -fsanitize=undefined,address -g
```

And the same goes with clang.

```
clang++ -Wextra -O0 -fsanitize=undefined,address -g
```

Compiler versions are: 9.3.0 for g++ and 10.0.0 for clang.

I found even funnier example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int x;
    cout << x;
}
```

This one gives a warning on g++, but no warning on clang.
How can it be resolved? Why a compiler wouldn't warn me about such silly mistakes?
Is it a problem with WSL or is it expected compiler behaviour?

Comment: Looks like since `a` and `b` are not known until runtime, the compilers don't try to check what memory you're accessing.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili I was thinking about it, but the second example is something that should be definitely caught.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah but you get no warnings in compilation phase, only during runtime when trying to read uninitialized memory

Comment: @LightFelicis  Ahh. I misunderstood the question!

Comment: No worries. BTW on runtime, I'm getting integer overflow, because of adding those uninitialized values XD

Comment: Your second example does give a warning with `-Wall -Wextra` on clang (and gcc) https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/v7er8z

Comment: As @AyxanHaqverdili mentioned, try to add `-Wall` in your compiler options. I guess uninitialized variable access warnings are raised with this option (as most of the common warnings).

Comment: invoking the compiler with its default parameters can do the most funny things. I suggest  `-Wall -Werror -pedantic`